# Is expected value of a bounded below function bounded below?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, functions, probability-distributions, upper-lower-bounds

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded below function and let $X \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a random vector. Is $\mathbb{E}_{X}[f(X)]$ bounded below?

**My try**

$X$ is a random vector that is distributed by some unknown distribution $\mathcal{D}$. Thus, one can write the following:

$$
\mathbb{E}_{X}[f(X)] = \int_{x_1,\dots,x_n}f(x)dx_1\dots dx_n
$$
how can we show that the above integral is bounded below?

Comment: In general, if $f\ge 0$ then $\int f \ge 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity, let's relabel your function. Let $h:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be bounded below, and let $X \in D$ be distributed according to some pdf $f$. In particular, $f \ge 0$ and $\int_D f(x)\ dx = 1$.

Since $h$ is bounded below, then $h(x) \ge M$ for all $x$, thus,
$$
\mathbb{E}[h(X)]
 = \int_D h(x) f(x)\ dx
 \ge \int_D M f(x)\ dx
 = M \int_D f(x)\ dx
 = M
$$
where the integral inequality is valid since $f(x) \ge 0$.

---

**UPDATE**

Following the suggestion of @Adayah below, note the above proof only works for continuously distributed random vectors, but if $\mu$ is a general distribution, we can generalize the argument by
$$
\mathbb{E}[h(X)]
 = \int_D h(x) \ d\mu(x)
 \ge \int_D M \ d\mu(x)
 = M \int_D \ d\mu(x)
 = M
$$

Comment: This proof only works for continuously distributed random vectors, but replacing $f(x) \, dx$ with $d \mu$ in each integral gives a general proof (where $\mu$ denotes the distribution of $X$).

Comment: @Adayah +1, added an update to the answer explaining your point